# No results returned from phonegap sql database query

Tags: jquery, sql, cordova

I am attempting to query a phonegap SQL database which contains a list of vehicles. If I load the vehicle registration form a storage variable and run the query as is below I get no rows returned but I am sure the record exists!  If I hard code the same registration as var veh = "ABC 123" and run the query against this I get a row returned.  I am at a loss to understand why the strings look identical!  Can anyone show me where my error is?

```
function getVehicleClass() {
     var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Vehicles List", 200000);
    db.transaction(QueryDB);
}
function QueryDB(tx) {
    var veh = localStorage.getItem('_reg');
    console.log(veh);

    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Vehicles where Registration="' + veh + '"' , [], successCB, errorCB);   
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}

function successCB(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("Vehicle query: " + len + " rows found.");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =" + results.rows.item(i).Registration + " " + results.rows.item(i).class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure var veh = localStorage.getItem('_reg'); is returning the right value?

Try to add this log: console.log('typeof veh: ' + typeof veh);
before the command "console.log(veh);".

What the log says about it?

Comment: Hi the log returns a String:  typeof veh: string

Comment: Is there any blank space before/after your string? Did you tri to add .trim()?

Comment: Yes added  $.trim(veh); the result is the same.

Comment: I don't know where's the problem. Try this: var veh = JSON.parse(localStorage._reg || null) and check again the log.

Comment: Adding  var veh = JSON.parse(localStorage._reg || null) causes a syntax error!

Comment: Hi Andreaoid  I found the error I was not using trim correctly so the string was not correct.  I have fixed the code and it is now working correctly thankyou.